# How can I divide the number value of a key by a constant using yq?

Tags: division, yq

Having an input YML (example: size in MB)

```
a: 2048
```

I want to have the output (example: size in GB):

```
2
```

But using the [divide operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/divide):

```
echo "a: 2048" | yq eval '.a / 1024' -
```

I get an error:

```
Error: 1:4: invalid input text "/ 1024"
```

How to do number division in yq?

**Note**: I don't want to manipulate the input YML by adding a 2nd (divisor key `b: 1024`).

Comment: what version are you using? 
Using latest version (`v4.32.2`), this `echo "a: 2048" | yq '.a / 1024'` worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found the particular issue responsible with the error above:

```
==> Upgrading yq
  4.30.8 -> 4.32.2
```

Divide was either not implemented or faulty in `v4.30.8` but it works as documented in `v4.32.2`

Comment: Version [4.32.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.32.1) has "added divide and modulo operators".